# str_split() within filter()

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe with an ID (V1) and some columns that contain strings with comma-separated values, i.e., "a,b" (V2). I want to filter the dataframe based on a match between any of a vector of values and any of the values in this string. I also want to preserve any other columns without naming them explicitly (V3).

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = 1:4, V2 = c("a,b", letters[1:3]), V3 = letters[20:23])
head(df)
  V1  V2 V3
1  1 a,b  t
2  2   a  u
3  3   b  v
4  4   c  w
```

The output should contain any rows in which at least one part of V2 matches at least one of the values in a vector of values. I.e., if the criterion is c("a","b"), rows 1:3 should be preserved in full; if the criterion is c("a","d"), rows 1:2 should be preserved, etc. I would also like to preserve the complete string in V2.

I know I can use separate_rows, filter on the separated rows, then summarise (or aggregate) the dataframe again:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(V2, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by_at(setdiff(names(df), "V2")) %>%
  filter(V2 %in% c("a", "b")) %>%
  summarise(paste(V2, collapse=","))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [3]
     V1 V3    `paste(V2, collapse = ",")`
  <int> <chr> <chr>                      
1     1 t     a,b                        
2     2 u     a                          
3     3 v     b
```

However, this has the disadvantage that the original string is not preserved. This makes a differences when not all parts of the string are contained in the critertion:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(V2, sep = ",") %>%
  group_by_at(setdiff(names(df), "V2")) %>%
  filter(V2 %in% c("a", "d")) %>%
  summarise(paste(V2, collapse=","))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   V1 [2]
     V1 V3    `paste(V2, collapse = ",")`
  <int> <chr> <chr>                      
1     1 t     a                          
2     2 u     a
```

I was wondering whether there is a solution that uses str_split() or a similar function directly inside filter(). Because this would return a TRUE/FALSE value for each part of the string, I tried to combine them using any(). This, however, does not work, because it is applied to any value returned by str_split() across the entire data frame:

```
# This does not include comma-separated values
df %>%
  filter(
    str_split(V2, ",") %in% c("a", "b")
  )
  V1 V2 V3
1  2  a  u
2  3  b  v

# This does not filter out non-matching values
df %>%
  filter(
    any(str_split(V2, ",") %in% c("a", "b"))
  )
  V1  V2 V3
1  1 a,b  t
2  2   a  u
3  3   b  v
4  4   c  w
```

Comment: What do you mean by `original string is not preserved.` ? What is your expected output for `c("a","b")` and `c("a","d")` ?

Comment: Or maybe something like `df %>% filter(grepl("a", V2) == TRUE | grepl("b", V2) == TRUE) `?

Comment: @rdatasculptor No need for `== TRUE` (in particular here, but also in general).

Comment: @RonakShah The values in V2 are not preserved completely---the parts of the string that do not match the criterion are dropped. For `c("a", "d")`, row 1 returns `a`; I would prefer `"a,b"`.

Comment: It depends on how your real data looks like. For the toy data above `df %>% filter(str_detect(V2, "[ab]"))` would be enough, but I doubt that it will work on your original data.

Comment: @rdatasculptor grepl() does not work because parts of the actual strings might overlap. E.g., there might be "a", "ab", "aba"... filtering "ab" would erroneously retain "aba". This is not clear from the example, apologies for that.

Comment: @simoncolumbus, yes I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this approach can help with you original data (note that I updated your `df` as mentioned in your comments).

The idea is to first use `str_split` on `V2` which will turn it into a list, then use `map_lgl` to loop over the list with `str_detect` wrapped in `any` to return exactly one `TRUE` or `FALSE` per row. Within the `str_detect` we are looking for exact matches of `a` or `b` by wrapping them in `^$`. And we can do this all inside `filter` without adding a new variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(V1 = 1:4, V2 = c("a,b", "a", "b", "aba"), V3 = letters[20:23])

df %>% 
  filter(map_lgl(str_split(V2, ","),
                 ~ any(str_detect(.x, "^a$|^b$"))))
#>   V1  V2 V3
#> 1  1 a,b  t
#> 2  2   a  u
#> 3  3   b  v
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks---this is perfect. Because I am using vectors defined elsewhere for the criterion, I replaced str_detect with %in%: 

`df %>% filter(map_lgl(str_split(V2, ","), ~ any(.x %in% c("a", "b"))))`

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of splitting the string you could think of creating a pattern to filter.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

get_rows <- function(data, vec) {
  data %>%
    filter(str_detect(V2, str_c(vec, collapse = '|')))
}

get_rows(df, c('a', 'b'))
#  V1  V2 V3
#1  1 a,b  t
#2  2   a  u
#3  3   b  v

get_rows(df, c('a', 'd'))
#  V1  V2 V3
#1  1 a,b  t
#2  2   a  u
```

You can write this in base R as well :

```
get_rows <- function(data, vec) {
  subset(data, grepl(paste0(vec, collapse = '|'), V2))
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work correctly, when df is like `data.frame(V1 = 1:4, V2 = c("a,b", "a", "b", "aba"), V3 = letters[20:23])` as specified in the comments by the OP. In this case also `get_rows(df, c('^a$', '^b$'))` won't help.